# Generic type interplay with Union type

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I use a `Generic` class in python, whose instances are little but wrappers around instances of other types:

```py
import random
from typing import Generic
from typing import TypeVar
from typing import Union

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)


class Wrapper(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T) -> None:
        self._value = value

    @property
    def unwrap(self) -> T:
        return self._value


def test_union_wrapper() -> None:
    def wrapper_union() -> Wrapper[Union[str, int]]:
        if random.random() >= 0.5:
            return Wrapper("foo")
        else:
            return Wrapper(42)

    # mypy will give an error for this line
    w_u: Union[Wrapper[str], Wrapper[int]] = wrapper_union()
```

Running `mypy` on the above code will result in:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Wrapper[Union[str, int]]", variable has type "Union[Wrapper[str], Wrapper[int]]")
```

This might seem reasonable, because

`Wrapper[Union[str, int]]` ≮: `Wrapper[str]`, and
`Wrapper[Union[str, int]]` ≮: `Wrapper[int]`

and, as can be read in [PEP483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#covariance-and-contravariance):

> `Union` behaves covariantly in all its arguments. Indeed, as discussed above, `Union[t1, t2, ...]` is a subtype of `Union[u1, u2, ...]`, if `t1` is a subtype of `u1`, etc.

But I take issue with it, because I know that ∀w ∈ `Wrapper[Union[str, int]]`, w ∈ `Wrapper[str]` or w ∈ `Wrapper[int]`, hence, `Wrapper[Union[str, int]]` <: `Union[Wrapper[str], Wrapper[int]]`, regardless. I would like to get `mypy` to recognize the same fact, but I don't know how.

There is even an example of such a recognition using the standard library. If I replace `Wrapper` with `Type` - another covariant `Generic` - in the code above, we get:

```py
def test_union_type() -> None:
    def type_union() -> Type[Union[str, int]]:
        if random.random() >= 0.5:
            return str
        else:
            return int

    # mypy has no problem with this
    w_u: Union[Type[str], Type[int]] = type_union()
```

Here, `mypy` recognizes that the function return type, `Type[Union[str, int]]` is equivalent to the variable type, `Union[Type[str], Type[int]]`.

I thus have two questions:

1. How do I tell a type checker that `Wrapper` behaves as `Type` does with regards to `Union`?
2. Does this behavior with regards to `Union` have a name? If we treat Wrapper and Unions as functions on types, we could say that they [commute with each other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Properties), but not sure what the right term is in the context of type theory, or Python specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I found an unsatisfying solution to Q1, using a mypy pluging with the following type analyzer hook:

```py
def commute_with_union_hook(ctx: AnalyzeTypeContext) -> Type:
    sym = ctx.api.lookup_qualified(ctx.type.name, ctx.type)
    node = sym.node
    if not ctx.type.args and len(ctx.type.args) == 1:
        return ctx.api.analyze_type_with_type_info(node, ctx.type.args, ctx.type)

    t: Type = ctx.type.args[0]
    t = ctx.api.anal_type(t)

    if not isinstance(t, UnionType):
        wrapper = ctx.api.analyze_type_with_type_info(node, ctx.type.args, ctx.type)
        return wrapper
    else:
        union_wrapper = UnionType.make_union(
            items=[Instance(typ=node, args=[item]) for item in t.items]
        )
        return union_wrapper
```

Feels overkill, but it might be the only way.